# Traerme en un array los meses del año y colocar el actual php

Tags: php, array

Buenos días estoy construyendo este array para traerme todos los meses del año y por default me deje el mes en curso pero no logro que funcione el array. Acá dejo el código

```
<?php   
    $fsis = date("Y m d h i a");
    list($sano, $smes, $sdia, $shora, $smin, $sap ) = explode(" ", $fsis);
    echo"
    <select name=\"envio_mes\">
        <option value=\"0\">Mes</option>\n";
            for($i = 1; $i < count($mes); $i++){
                echo"<option value=\""; 
                if($i < 10){ 
                    echo"0$i"; 
                }else{ 
                    echo"$i"; 
                } 
                echo"\""; 
                if($smes == $i){
                    echo" selected"; 
                } 
                echo">$mes[$i]
                </option>\n";
            }
        echo"</select>"     
?>
```

Comment: Fijate que ordene el codigo y se ven varios problemas.. el select nunca se cierra.. de donde vienen todos esos valores?

Comment: Y si pones count( $smes )... $mes no existe en la declaración

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres con que de donde vienen todos esos valores, cuales valores?

Comment: Todos esos valores que usas en este codigo, las variables..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te faltaba el arreglo con los nombres de los meses, para que funcionara tu condicion de parada en el ciclo con count($mes), lo que en este caso seria $i <= ya que comienzas con $i=1, en fin aki esta mi respuesta

```
<?php 
    //Obtengo la fecha con un formato determinado para poder separarlo por parte  
    $fsis = date("Y m d h i a");
    //Arreglo con los nombres de los meses
    $mes = ['enero','febrero','marzo','abril','mayo','junio','julio','agosto','septiembre','octubre','noviembre','diciembre'];
    //Voy separando en variables las partes de la fecha ke me interesan
    list($sano, $smes, $sdia, $shora, $smin, $sap ) = explode(" ", $fsis);
    //Creo el select con un option inicial
    echo "
    <select name=\"envio_mes\">
        <option value=\"0\">Mes</option>\n";
            //Recorro el arreglo de nombres de meses y voy creando los options correspondientes
            for($i = 1; $i <= count($mes); $i++){
                //Inicializo la etiqueta del option
                echo"<option value=\""; 
                if($i < 10){ 
                    echo "0$i"; 
                }else{ 
                    echo "$i"; 
                } 
                echo "\""; 
                //Si coincide el mes de la iteracion con el actual lo pongo seleccionado
                if($smes == $i){
                    echo" selected"; 
                } 
                //Establezco como valor a mostrar el nombre del mes correspondiente a la iteración actual
                echo ">".$mes[$i-1]."
                </option>\n";
                //Y cierro la etiqueta del option
            }
        //Cierro la etiqueta del select
        echo"</select>"     
?>
```

Comment: Listo, con esto solucione pero extrañamente estoy viendo un array donde no crea los meses del año en un array y los muestras, sigo leyendo el codigo para ver de donde los invoca porque no hay ni un include, ni require.

Comment: el nombre de los meses se muestra en la linea donde dice **echo ">".$mes[$i-1]**

Comment: No me entiendes Darie, quiero decir que tengo un codigo que estoy trabajando donde no esta declarado el array $mes = ['enero','febrero','etc']; y aun asi funciona.

Comment: Ya lo vi, lo tiene declarado en un archivo de funciones, en una funcion globlal en otra carpeta, pero como puede invocarlo en este archivo sin un include o require?, lo extraño es que para un archivo si me funciona pero para otro no.

Comment: Por eso fue ke lo cree pk no lo tenias en el codigo original y sin embargo lo llamabas en la variable $mes que en tu pregunta no aparecia por ningun lado

Comment: Solo esa ultima pregunta amigo, por que si tengo esa variable declarada global en una funcion en otro archivo para un archivo si me fuciona y para otro no?

Comment: Si lo tienes global debe funcionar para todos, pero si te presenta eso un problema puedes en vez de declararla como variable global lo haces como una funcion que te la devuelva y solucionado el dilema

Answer (score 2):

Declaramos el Select:

```
<select name="mes" class="form-control" id="mes">
```

A continuación declaramos los meses y hacemos un `for` para que recorra el array:

```
<?php    
$Meses = array('Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio',
       'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre');

for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) {
     if ($i == date('m'))
echo '<option value="'.$i.'"selected>'.$Meses[($i)-1].'</option>';
     else
echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$Meses[($i)-1].'</option>';
     }
?>
```

Finalmente cerramos con la etiqueta:

```
</select>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, util tu comentario!